# rails controller action + rendering bug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, model, controller

I have notification system in my app. When the user goes to other user's page (users/show page), the notification count gets decreased since he/she can see the common chat window. So for instance if sby texted you then you have 1 notification. When you get on the sender's show page your notifications gets decreased to 0.

Everything worked fine, but I wanted to refactor the code since it was getting cluttered.

Below you can see the old and the new code. The old code works fine but there is a weird problem with the new code. When I get to the user page and I print out the `current_user.new_chat_notification` attribute in the controller show action or in the template (I show it in the header so it's available on every page) it shows 1. In the meantime if I print out the number in the console it shows 0. So for some reason the number gets decreased in the db, but the controller action and the view don't know about it in time. If I go to an other page then the number goes down to zero. So the next controller action already knows that the number was decreased and shows 0. I don't really understand what's the difference between the old and new code that can causes something like this.

schema.rb

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "new_chat_notification",  default: 0
end
```

users controller

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  #FOLLOWING 3 LINES ARE PART OF THE UPDATE
  @conversation = Conversation.create_or_find_conversation(current_user.id, @user.id)
  @tasks = Task.uncompleted.between(current_user.id, @user.id).order("created_at DESC").includes(:assigner, :executor).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 14)
  @messages = @conversation.messages.includes(:user).order(created_at: :desc).limit(50).reverse
  current_user.decreasing_chat_notification_number(@user)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js { render template: "tasks/between.js.erb" }
  end
end
```

user.rb

```
#FOLLOWING 2 LINES ARE PART OF THE UPDATE
has_many :notifications, foreign_key: "recipient_id", dependent: :destroy
validates :new_chat_notification, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }

def decreasing_chat_notification_number(sender)
  notification = notifications.between_chat_recipient(sender).unchecked.first
  checking_and_decreasing_notification(notification) if notification.present?
end

def checking_and_decreasing_notification(notification)
  notification.check_notification
  if notification.notifiable_type == "Message"
    # decrease_new_chat_notifications --> OLD CODE THAT WORKING PROPERLY
    NotificationSender.new(notification).decrease_new_chat_notifications # --> NEW CODE NOT WORKING PROPERLY
    ....
  else
    ....
  end
end

def decrease_new_chat_notifications
  decrement!(:new_chat_notification) if new_chat_notification > 0
end
```

notification_sender.rb (for new code)

```
class NotificationSender
  attr_reader :notification, :recipient

  def initialize(notification)
    @notification = notification
    @recipient = notification.recipient
  end

  def decrease_new_chat_notifications
    recipient.decrement!(:new_chat_notification) if recipient.new_chat_notification > 0
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference may be in the fact that this line:

```
@recipient = notification.recipient
```

may load the recipient from the database, resetting the state. It's not obvious from your code whether there is any state change in the `User` model before the `decreasing_chat_notification_number` gets called.

**UPDATE**

If this is in fact the reason for the issue (which is currently just an unsupported suggestion), you could load your referenced recipient along with the notification. This way the it's state will not unexpectedly be updated from the database when you're initializing the `NotificationSender`.

Instead of `notification = notifications.between_chat_recipient(sender).unchecked.first`, try this:

```
notification = notifications.
    between_chat_recipient(sender).
    unchecked.
    includes(:recipient).
    first
```

The exact query may be different depending on your associations, but again, the idea is to load the recipient in the same database call as the notification, thus removing the potential race condition.

Comment: Nic, what do you mean by "it's not obvious from your code"? Should I show something else as well? If that's the problem what you say, what should I change in the code to make it work?

Comment: Sorry I haven't provided the recommendations. See my updated answer. 'Not obvious' means there are probably some other parts of the code which might play a role but its not clear whether they are in the controller or the model or both. Try the recommendation first and if it doesn't resolve the issue, please add complete code of the `users#show` action and the `User` model to your question.

Comment: Nic, added the relevant parts. There is also Pusher gem for live notifications, but if I delete the Pusher trigger part from the `checking_and_decreasing_notification` method in the user.rb (where I have `....`) the problem is still there. On the other part of the if else statement there is other_notifications, that work like chat notifications, just the notifiable_type is different. I have the same problem with that as well, just tried to trim the question. I tried your solution, but didn't work. It's super weird since I don't see the difference between the old and the new code.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I just don't even know where I should start searching :O